# 81/5000 Display browser image created by PHP's GD library using Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, gd

I have the following code to display in the browser an image created through the GD library, I am using CodeIgniter. But the image is not displayed when I am running on the production server.
However the same script running in pure PHP works perfectly on the server. Is Codeigniter blocking something, is there any settings I can use?

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');


class Tarefa_gd extends MY_Controller 
{
    function __construct()
    {
        $this->_modulo      = MODULO_APP;
        $this->_controller  = strtolower( __CLASS__ );

        $this->_verifica_usuario_logado_app();

        parent::__construct();
    }



     function color()
    {
        $my_img = imagecreate( 200, 80 );
        $background = imagecolorallocate( $my_img, 0, 0, 255 );
        $text_colour = imagecolorallocate( $my_img, 255, 255, 0 );
        $line_colour = imagecolorallocate( $my_img, 128, 255, 0 );
        imagestring( $my_img, 4, 30, 25, "thesitewizard.com", $text_colour );
        imagesetthickness ( $my_img, 5 );
        imageline( $my_img, 30, 45, 165, 45, $line_colour );

        header( "Content-type: image/png" );
        imagepng( $my_img );
        imagecolordeallocate( $line_colour );
        imagecolordeallocate( $text_colour );
        imagecolordeallocate( $background );
        imagedestroy( $my_img );
    }

}
?>
```

Comment: `function color()` it's working fine. I tried it with custom php, and also put it into a codeigniter controller, what is error that you get ?

Comment: So, no error returns just no image generated
I'm sending an example of the same script one in CI and another not.
Running on the same server.

**Example with Codeigniter with Error:**
[link](https://codigo.legal/teste/Tarefa_gd/color)

**Example Without Codeigniter, Pure PHP Works**
[link](https://codigo.legal/gd/index.php)

I believe it is something in CI that is blocking, but I couldn't figure out what unfortunately.

Comment: both of your projects using the same php versions ? if there are separate php versions installed on the server, check if you GD library is enabled in php.ini